# How to convert this primal linear program to dual and solve the dual problem?

Tags: linear-programming

How do I convert the following primal problem to its dual and finally solve the dual?
Maximize Z=x1+2x2+x3 subject to x1+x2−x3≤2, x1−x2+x3=1, 2x1+x2+x3≥2; x1 ≥ 0, x2 ≤ 0, x3 unrestricted in sign?
I have used the primal-dual correspondence table to find the dual directly from the primal problem. In my given problem, after deriving the dual, the first constraint becomes greater than equal to, second one becomes less than equal and the third one is equal to. y1≥0, y2 unrestricted and y3≤0. Now to convert this to a standard form I am stuck because I introduced y2=y4-y5, y3=-y6 and slack and surplus variables from constraints 1 and 2 respectively. But the problem is, this way I have a total of 8 variables y1,y2,….y8. If I start with the first tableau of the dual simplex, I have 3 constraints but only 2 basic variables y7 and y8 which can never be the case. I am sure I am doing something wrong but what is it. Please help me out! How do I proceed after deriving the dual in order to solve it?

Comment: The dual simplex method actually works on the primal. No need to create a dual model if, as you say, you are using a dual simplex method.

Comment: I was asked to convert the primal to its dual and then solve it. I tried doing it using primal simplex but I am stuck. I used the primal-dual correspondence table to find the dual of the LP using w1,w2,w3 where the variable sign restriction. I made w2=w4-w5 and w3=-w6 and converted to standard form both at once introducing slack and surplus variables w7 and w8 in the first and second constraints respectively. I added two artificial variables w9 and w10 to the first and third constraints respectively. I tried to use the Big-M Method to get  initial basic feasible solution.  @ErwinKalvelagen